# Pass decimal less than 0.1 from C# to SQL - SQL Profiler Interpretation Issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I can not pass decimal value less than `0.1` properly from C# to SQL
when I pass value from C# for example decimal value `0.0033M` I get `33` in SQL Profiler

```c#
db.Insert(0.0033M);//SP Called from EDMX context `db` C#
```

When I check In **SQL Profiler** I get

```sql
exec [dbo].[Insert] @Value=33 --Shouldn't it be 0.0033
```

But when I pass any value more than equal to `0.1` the value is passed properly

How to pass decimal value properly from C# to decimal of stored procedure?

---

Here is our SP it doesn't matter it is just to make things more clear actual value is what we received in Profiler that I mentioned earlier

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert]  
 @Value[decimal](18, 6) NULL
AS            
BEGIN            
        Select @Value  -- this would give `33` when passed `0.0033M` From C#      
END
```

---

**Modified**:

I am very grateful of **David Browne - Microsoft** for answering. As he mentioned there is no issue with it yes there is no issue in passing value. But on our further investigation we did found that its **SQL Profiler** who is interpreting it wrong while SQL and C# working perfectly. Here I will do mention we did tests with ADO.net and Entity Framework and found that the issue is with what SQL Profiler is interpreting that is when less than `0.1` is passed SQL profiler shows values wrong, it is showing  `0.01` as `1` and `0.077` as `77`. I am very grateful for every people who participated but I also want to mention this here as an abnormal behaviour that SQL Profiler did not provided result as expected because for many debugging scenarios we use SQL Profiler.

Comment: How is your field defined in SQL? Is it DECIMAL(18,0)? If you need more decimals, just change it to DECIMAL(18,NUM_OF_DECIMAL_PLACES).

Comment: what is 0.0033M?

Comment: @viveknuna The value 0.0033 expressed as a decimal in C#.

Comment: we are using DECIMAL(18,6) @Matt

Comment: And you are **actually** ***definitively*** calling it with a ***`decimal`*** of `0.0033M`, and not `decimal.Parse("0.0033")` or passing a string value to that parameter?

Comment: Its Like this Yes **Decimal** `decimal value = 0.09M; db.Insert(value);`

Comment: @AliJamal but how are you dealing with the value that is returned from `db.Insert(value)`?

Comment: Are there any EF Entities used with this? If so, how are the EF Entities defined?

Comment: @SeanT In My Real SP I am inserting Value in Table it is just an example (metaphor) just to show that I am not able to pass expected value below 0.1 to sql. I Have tried **Ado.net** and all methods of **entity framework** to call SP my value for example `0.0256` is converted to `256` which is a serious issue for me as I am using decimal.

Comment: @TonyAbrams yes there is a Table named `Bills` in real SP I am inserting values in it.

Comment: @AliJamal Are we sure the **value** is converted (which is hard to believe) or just the **text** representation (all the tools use some sort of value to string conversion for displaying the value). The last is simple formatting, and no issue at all. What do you see when you call `0.0033M.ToString()`?

Comment: So is it saved in the database as 33 on your real stored proc or returned as 33? It's a crucial difference

Comment: I am very grateful of **David Browne - Microsoft** for answering. As he mentioned there is no issue with it yes there is no issue in passing value. But on our further investigation we did found that its **SQL Profiler** who is interpreting it wrong while SQL and C# working perfectly.

Comment: Here I will do mention we did tests with ADO.net and Entity Framework and found that the issue is with what SQL Profiler is interpreting that is when less than `0.1` is passed SQL profiler shows values wrong, it is showing  `0.01` as `1` and `0.077` as `77`. I am very grateful for every people who participated but I also want to mention this here as an abnormal behaviour that SQL Profiler did not provided result as expected because for many debugging scenarios we use SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of EF?  I can't repro this with a simple EF6 EDMX-based database-first model.

Added this proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert]  
 @Value[decimal](18, 6) NULL
AS            
BEGIN            
        Select @Value  -- this would give `33` when passed `0.0033M` From C#      
END
```

Added a database-first model, which generated

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Nullable<decimal>> Insert(Nullable<decimal> value)
{
    var valueParameter = value.HasValue ?
        new ObjectParameter("Value", value) :
        new ObjectParameter("Value", typeof(decimal));

    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Nullable<decimal>>("Insert", valueParameter);
}
```

and ran:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp24
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new aEntities())
            {
                var result = db.Insert(0.0033M);
                Console.WriteLine(result.First().Value);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output was

```
0.003300
```

Comment: I am very grateful of **David Browne - Microsoft** for answering. As he mentioned there is no issue with it yes there is no issue in passing value. But on our further investigation we did found that its **SQL Profiler** who is interpreting it wrong while SQL and C# working perfectly.

Comment: Here I will do mention we did tests with ADO.net and Entity Framework and found that the issue is with what SQL Profiler is interpreting that is when less than `0.1` is passed SQL profiler shows values wrong, it is showing  `0.01` as `1` and `0.077` as `77`. I am very grateful for every people who participated but I also want to mention this here as an abnormal behaviour that SQL Profiler did not provided result as expected because for many debugging scenarios we use SQL Profiler.